# Run a spark scala script in a remote cluster setup on Azure databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have written a spark scala(sbt) application in intelliJ which I want to run on a remote cluster hosted on Azure databricks. What all steps to follow to avoid manually uploading jars into dbfs always to test the code

Answer (score 0):

Databricks Connect allows you to connect your favorite IDE (Eclipse, **IntelliJ**, PyCharm, RStudio, Visual Studio Code), notebook server (Jupyter Notebook, Zeppelin), and other custom applications to Databricks clusters.

Follow the steps given in this [official document](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#intellij-scala-or-java) to configure IntelliJ with Databricks cluster.

Comment: Thank you. My project uses maven but the documentation gives sbt reference process. How to provide unmanaged base reference in maven like sbt?